# Select element change event trigger (slow)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events

I've noticed in many web applications that focusing on a `select` element and typing a relevant `option` value will provide *much* faster `change` event triggers rather than clicking (or navigating with arrows) and selecting from the dropdown. I've tried it in a few browsers with mixed but similar results.

*Example*

[image]

*Example uses AngularJS with a `filter: { prop: value }`.*

It appears the browser waits for the `option` to appear in the `select` element before firing the `change` event.

Is there any way to speed up the click / arrow nav approach? other than rolling your own select element.